# R Plotly trouble with using datetime values for creating barplot with asymmetric error bars

Tags: r, plotly, lubridate

I am trying to create a bar plot that has with bars that represent median time and error bars that represent q3 and q1. Additionally I would like the values which start with a unit of seconds to be represented in MM:SS format ultimately.

I found some solutions here to recommend using datetime values and then only displaying the minutes & seconds since 1970/01/01 00:00:00 and that seems to work ok. But when I apply this solution, my error bars no longer are visible. I'm thinking error_y does not like working with datetime values. (I have to say I agree with it hahah).
Essentially I would like both of the results below to occur simultaneously in one figure.

Figure 3 is another dummy version closer to my original data manipulation and including suggested changes.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)
library(hms)

df <- data.frame(
  group = c("a", "b", "c"),
  median = c(71,75,70),
  q1 = c(20, 21, 19),
  q3 = c(137, 140, 135)
)

fig1 <- df %>% mutate(
  q1.s = duration(q1, "seconds"),
  med.s = duration(median, "seconds"),
  q3.s = duration(q3, "seconds"),
  low.s = duration(median-q1, "seconds"),
  up.s = duration(q3-median, "seconds")
  ) %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~group, 
          y = ~med.s, 
          type = 'bar', 
          name = ~group,
          error_y = list(type = 'data', 
                          symmetric= FALSE, 
                          arrayminus = ~low.s, 
                          array = ~up.s, 
                          color = '#000000')) %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Median Time'))
  
fig1


fig2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(q1.s = as.POSIXct(hms(duration(q1, "seconds")), format = "%H:%M:%S"),
         med.s = as.POSIXct(hms(duration(median, "seconds")), format = "%H:%M:%S"),
         q3.s = as.POSIXct(hms(duration(q3, "seconds")), format = "%H:%M:%S"),
         low.s = as.POSIXct(hms(duration(median-q1, "seconds")), format = "%H:%M:%S"),
         up.s = as.POSIXct(hms(duration(q3-median, "seconds")), format = "%H:%M:%S")) %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~group, 
          y = ~med.s, 
          type = 'bar', 
          name = ~group,
          error_y = ~list(type = 'data', 
                          symmetric= FALSE, 
                          arrayminus = ~low.s, 
                          array = ~up.s, 
                          color = '#000000')) %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Median Time', 
                      type = 'date',
                      tickformat="%M:%S",
                      range = c('1970-01-01 00:00:00','1970-01-01 00:02:30'))) 
  
fig2

df2 <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), times=5),
  t = c(0,0,0,20,21,19,71,75,70,137,140,135,240,240,240)
)

fig3 <- df2 %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(t.s = as.POSIXct(hms::hms(duration(t)), format = "%H:%M:%S")) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(answer.quantile = list(quantile(t.s,
                                                   probs = seq(.25, .75, by = .25),
                                                   na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  unnest_wider(answer.quantile) %>% 
  dplyr::rename(q1="25%", med="50%", q3="75%") %>%
  mutate(low = med-q1,
         up = q3-med) %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~group, 
          y = ~med, 
          type = 'bar', 
          name = ~group,
          error_y = list( 
                          symmetric= FALSE, 
                          arrayminus = ~low, 
                          array = ~up, 
                          color = '#000000')) %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Median Time',
                      type = 'date',
                      tickformat="%M:%S",
                      range = c('1970-01-01 00:00:00','1970-01-01 00:02:30')),
         xaxis = list(title = ' ', categoryorder='trace')) 

fig3
```

Comment: In `fig2`, use `hms::hms`, instead of `lubridate::hms`. If you keep everything else the same, I think you'll get the outcome you're looking for. (BTW, the mutate wasn't working...it wasn't even getting to Plotly before it said...uh, no...I don't wanna...)

Comment: thanks! I will give this a whirl. Yea I remember getting some errors when I was trying to write the dummy code. in my original code I wasn't getting that error and I was on a time crunch to get this posted and didn't really investigate.

Comment: @Kat I tried using the hms::hms and it did not yield the desired results. I have updated the code above and created a 3rd dummy version which is more concise and closer to the original code. This removed the warning on the mutate step, but the overall issue persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I left my comment about using `hms::hms()` I was only addressing part of the problem: the axes labels. Sorry about that.

Here's a solution to both the axis labels and the error bars. This is a workaround because Plotly doesn't support error bars on a date-type axis.

> [You can read about error bars and their lack of date-type support here.](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3722)

Starting with the libraries, this uses `htmlwidgets` (`htmlwidgets::onRender`) in addition to the libraries you were already using.

#### The data:

You can go back to `df`, your original data, because if you format this for dates, you can't keep the error bars--- or you have to add them as shapes.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

df <- data.frame(
  group = c("a", "b", "c"),
  median = c(71,75,70),
  q1 = c(20, 21, 19),
  q3 = c(137, 140, 135)
)
```

We're going to create a `customdata` object for the hover content representing the y-axis using a UDF.

Here's that number-modifying function.

```
nfm <- function(val) {   # format the numbers in m:ss format
  lapply(val, \(x) {     # for each in val
    m = floor(x/60)      # id minutes
    s = x %% 60          # id seconds
    ifelse(s == 0, paste0(m, ":00"), 
           paste0(m, ":", formatC(s, width = 2, flag = 0)))
  }) %>% unlist()        # return a vector of strings m:ss
}
```

#### The plot:

Finally, call the plot and `onRender`. In the plot, since we're using `df`, you'll see `median` instead of `med`, the addition of `customdata` and `hovertemplate`. You'll also see that `arrayminus`, and `array` are different as well.

In `layout`, you'll see that `yaxis` only calls for a title modification now.

In `onRender`, you'll see `trfm`, this does the same thing as `nfm` did to create `customdata`, only this is in Javascript. `frmtMe` calls the html elements that are associated with the y ticks. If the labels don't contain a ":" then they modify the content using `trfm`. Next, `frmtMe` is called for the initial plot. The last element of `onRender` is `el.on`, which triggers `frmtMe` if the plot is resized, zoomed, etc. --anything that may cause the y-axis to change.

```
df %>%              # using df instead of the date-formatted data
    plot_ly(x = ~group, y = ~median, type = 'bar', name = ~group,
            customdata = nfm(df$median),          # added customdata for tooltips
            hovertemplate = "%{x} %{customdata}", # using the customdata
            error_y = list( symmetric= FALSE, arrayminus = ~q1, 
                            array = ~(q3 - median), color = '#000000')
            ) %>% 
    layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Median Time'),
           xaxis = list(title = '', categoryorder='trace')) %>% 
    htmlwidgets::onRender(
      'function(el, x) {
      trfm = function(d){            /* reformat value */
        var mn = Math.floor(d/60);   /* divide the value by 60, rounding down */
        var sc = (d % 60);           /* find the modulo (remainder) when div by 60 */
        return (sc == 60 ? (mn+1) + ":00" : mn + ":" + (sc < 10 ? "0" : "") + sc)
      }                              /* return m:ss reformatted string */
      
      frmtMe = function() {          /* is formatting needed? */
        var here = document.querySelectorAll("g.ytick");    /* find the labels */
        here.forEach(function(it, ind) {                    /* call trfm() to reformat */
          if(!/:/.test(here[ind].firstChild.textContent)) { /* formatted if necessary */
              here[ind].firstChild.textContent = trfm(here[ind].firstChild.textContent)
          }
        });
      }
      frmtMe();                          /* format the intial plot */
      el.on("plotly_relayout", frmtMe);  /* reformat if necessary */
    }')
```

[image]

Let me know if anything is unclear or if you have questions.

Here's all the code above all in one place. (Easier copy + paste)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(
  group = c("a", "b", "c"),
  median = c(71,75,70),
  q1 = c(20, 21, 19),
  q3 = c(137, 140, 135)
)

nfm <- function(val) {   # format the numbers in m:ss format
  lapply(val, \(x) {     # for each in val
    m = floor(x/60)      # id minutes
    s = x %% 60          # id seconds
    ifelse(s == 0, paste0(m, ":00"), 
           paste0(m, ":", formatC(s, width = 2, flag = 0)))
  }) %>% unlist()        # return a vector of strings m:ss
}

df %>%              # using df instead of the date-formatted data
    plot_ly(x = ~group, y = ~median, type = 'bar', name = ~group,
            customdata = nfm(df$median),          # added customdata for tooltips
            hovertemplate = "%{x} %{customdata}", # using the customdata
            error_y = list( symmetric= FALSE, arrayminus = ~q1, 
                            array = ~(q3 - median), color = '#000000')
            ) %>% 
    layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Median Time'),
           xaxis = list(title = '', categoryorder='trace')) %>% 
    htmlwidgets::onRender(
      'function(el, x) {
      trfm = function(d){            /* reformat value */
        var mn = Math.floor(d/60);   /* divide the value by 60, rounding down */
        var sc = (d % 60);           /* find the modulo (remainder) when div by 60 */
        return (sc == 60 ? (mn+1) + ":00" : mn + ":" + (sc < 10 ? "0" : "") + sc)
      }                              /* return m:ss reformatted string */
      
      frmtMe = function() {          /* is formatting needed? */
        var here = document.querySelectorAll("g.ytick");    /* find the labels */
        here.forEach(function(it, ind) {                    /* call trfm() to reformat */
          if(!/:/.test(here[ind].firstChild.textContent)) { /* formatted if necessary */
              here[ind].firstChild.textContent = trfm(here[ind].firstChild.textContent)
          }
        });
      }
      frmtMe();                          /* format the intial plot */
      el.on("plotly_relayout", frmtMe);  /* reformat if necessary */
    }')
```

Comment: amazing! I would vote it up but I don't have enough points here. But, no wonder I couldn't figure it out, that solution was way beyond my scope. Thank you for your expertise.